# Notation for random variables—differentiating between X and x

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I understand that P(X<x) is the probability that the random variable X is less than a fixed constant x. Assuming X is a normal random variable, would it be correct to use X or x in each of the following?

1. Find the value of X (or x...?) that separates the lowest 10% from the rest of the population.
2. In the solution to the question above, would it be correct to use X=____ or x=____?
3. When graphing a normal distribution, should the horizontal axis be labeled X or x? And should it be referred to as the X-axis or x-axis?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can see random variables as maps from a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ to for example the real numbers, $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$. So $X$ is your map and the small $x$ is one value of your mapping, i.e., for some value $\omega\in\Omega$ you have $X(\omega)=x$ just as in regular notation $f$ would be a mapping and $f(t) = y$ a value in your desired space of values of $f$.

1.) Concerning your first question you want to know which value $x$ seperates the lowest 10% from the Rest. So you want to know something about the value space (also called population) of your RV $X$. Hence, in this case you are interested in a small $x_0$ such that $P(X<x_0) = 0.1$.

2.) Neither nor since you are not wondering about the probability of one exact value but of an ensemble of values, $P(X<x_0) = 0.1$is the correct way of writing it.

3.) Definitely $x$ since  by 1.) $X$ is a map so it does not make sense to label an axis by the name of a map.

Hope that helps.